# Same RSA key on multiple PCs

Tags: ssh, authentication, rsa

Can I use my RSA private key on multiple computers i.e. my desktop and laptop. Or do I have to create a unique key for each computer I own, and add their respective public keys to necessary servers/programs.

Comment: see also: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/10203/2944

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, but you shouldn't.

Each device should get its own keypair. This makes recovery from a lost or stolen device much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Although it's technically correct, it's not a good advice.